# Iterating through text file via batch script without for statement

Tags: batch-file

I need a way to either not use the for statement, or find a way to break out of the looping process if a condition is met.

Here's what I have now...

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('type pclist.txt') do (
  ping -n 1 %%a | findstr /i "reply" >nul 2>nul
  if %errorlevel% equ 0 (
    if exist "\\%%a\c$\windows\temp\installed.txt" (
      echo %%a - Already installed >>results.txt
    )
    if not exist "\\%%a\c$\windows\temp\installed.txt" (
      echo %%a - Not installed >>results.txt
    )
  )
  ping -n 1 %%a | findstr /i "timed" >nul 2>nul
  if %errorlevel% equ 0 echo %%a - No PING response >>results.txt
  ping -n 1 %%a | findstr /i "transmit" >nul 2>nul
  if %errorlevel% equ 0 echo %%a - PING transmit failed >>results.txt
)
```

This gives me this kind of result...

```
192.168.144.1 - Already installed
192.168.144.1 - No PING response
192.168.144.1 - PING transmit failure
192 168.144.2 - Already installed
192.168.144.2 - No PING response
192.168.144.2 - PING transmit failure
192.168.144.3 - Not installed
192.168.144.3 - No PING response
192.168.144.3 - PING transmit failure
```

What I'd like to do is be able to exit the for loop when whatever first condition is met. So, I would have this kind of result instead...

```
192.168.144.1 - Already installed
192 168.144.2 - Already installed
192.168.144.3 - Not installed
```

I'm hoping I'm simply overlooking something simple and this will be just another one of those I-D-10-T errors for me. (lol)

Thanx in advance.

---

In plain English. Here's the goal:

```
Using FOR command, read list of IP addresses from text file.
  For each IP address read, PING and check response.
    If PING returns a reply, check for existence of file.
      If file exists,
        ECHO value 1 to results file, end FOR loop, proceed with next IP address in list.
      If file does not exist,
        ECHO value 2 to results file, end FOR loop, proceed with next IP address in list.
    If PING does not return a reply, ECHO PING error text to results file, end FOR loop, proceed with next IP address in list.
```

I hope that's a bit more understandable.

Thanx again.

Comment: You are not really explaining when you want those last 4 lines of code to run if at all.  My ping results do not have the word **timed** or **transmit**.  What are you trying to do with those ping resulsts?

Comment: I don't understand your concern; however: **1.** A `goto` command break a `for /f` loop. **2.** Your code needs to use Delayed Expansion to access the `!errorlevel!` inside the for loop, although in this case it is not necessary: just use the `if errorlevel 1 (` form (and change the code accordingly).

Comment: Sorry 'bout that. The possible PING results I can receive are... "Reply from ip.add.re.ss: bytes=## time=#ms TTL=###" or "Reply from ip.add.re.ss: Destination host unreachable." or "Ping request could not find host ip.add.re.ss. Please check the name and try again." or "Request timed out." or "PING: transmit failed. General failure." Therefore, I look for those findstr results above. Based on the ping result received, the goal is to echo a statement to a file. Now, multiple echos appear per ping instead of one and done.

Comment: So if I use a goto command to divert outside the for loop, how does it return?

Comment: I suggest you to _describe_ your problem using _plain English_ (not Batch code). For example, you refer to _"exit the for loop when whatever first condition is met"_, but we have not idea what "first condition" is... And **edit your question**! Do NOT post extensive details in comments...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid nested IF/Else code blocks you should use subs with calls. The use of `C:\windows\temp` might also be a problem when redirected to `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Temp`. TTL is a better indicator for the ping - less depending on the locale.

```
@Echo off
Set Res=^>^>Results.txt
Echo %date% %time% %Res:~1%
Set Inst=Windows\temp\installed.txt
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('type pclist.txt') do Call :TestPC %%a
Type %Res:~2%
Goto :Eof

:TestPC
ping -n 1 -w 500 %1|findstr "TTL">nul 2>&1||(Call :Check %1 &Goto :Eof)
:: A rights Problem might exist
if     exist "\\%1\c$\%Inst%" echo %1 - Already installed %Res%
if not exist "\\%1\c$\%Inst%" echo %1 - Not installed %Res%
Goto :Eof

:Check
ping -n 1 -w 500 %1 | findstr /i "timed" >nul 2>nul
if %errorlevel% equ 0 %Res% echo %1 - No PING response
ping -n 1 -w 500 %1 | findstr /i "transmit" >nul 2>nul
if %errorlevel% equ 0 %Res% echo %1 - PING transmit failed
Goto :Eof
```

returns this output

```
Mi 10/26/2016 17:46:35,78
192.168.3.91 - Not installed
192.168.3.95 - No PING response
192.168.3.92 - Already installed
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you very much, LotPings!

Answer (score 0):

```
  if %errorlevel% equ 0 (
```

(used multiple times) - `%errorlevel%` refers to the value of `errorlevel` **at the time the FOR is parsed** not at run-time. You need to substitute

```
if not errorlevel 1
```

in each case to provide the required functionality (if run-time errorlevel is not (1 or greater))

Hence, you "sample current output" is bogus - you cannot get that output with the code you've shown as `%errorlevel%` will not change with each loop. Furthermore, your sample shows "failure" whereas you code specifies "failed".

What do you mean by `whatever first condition is met` ? You could get your proposed output by simply removing or commenting-out the 4 lines following the closure of your `if` statement.

Comment: I modified the OP with (hopefully) a better explanation. Thanx.